# titleformat has no effect!

Tags: sectioning, color, titlesec

I have tried to specify the color for my section as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275770/modifying-section-to-make-it-colorful-with-latex), but it has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\def\name{John Doe}

\def\footerlink{http://www.org.edu}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true,
  urlcolor = black,
  pdfauthor = {\name},
  pdfkeywords = {John Doe},
  pdftitle = {\name: Curriculum Vitae},
  pdfsubject = {Curriculum Vitae},
  pdfpagemode = UseNone
}

\geometry{
  body={6.8in, 10.0in},
  left=0.8in,
  top=0.5in
}

% Customize page headers
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{\name}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% Custom section fonts
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xspace}
\sectionfont{\rmfamily\mdseries\Large}
\subsectionfont{\rmfamily\mdseries\itshape\large}

\setlength\parindent{0em}

\newenvironment{noBullets}{
  \begin{list}{}{
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.0em}
  }
}{
  \end{list}
}


\titleformat{\section}
{\color{red}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{red}\thesection}{1em}{}


\begin{document}



{\Large \name}

\section*{Test section}
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using two conflicting packages, `sectsty` and `titlesec`. Use either of them, but not both.

If you use `sectsty` you can surely specify color with something like

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\normalfont\bfseries\Large\color{red}}
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\mdseries\itshape\large}
```